# Count times a multiple of a threshold has been exceeded

Tags: excel

I've got a single row of absolute values along the lines of this:

```
3001
3123
3342
3453
3561
```

Think of this as a growing graph with the individual values being connected. Now I want to count the amount of times the value of a cell has exceeded a certain threshold from the previous entry. Specifically, every time a number has exceeded a multiple of 500, I want the counter to go up.

So in this example, nothing happens until the very last entry, where the number went from 3453 to 3561 and thus surpassed the the 3500 threshold.

How would you do this?

Comment: So the next count would not happen till it passed 4000?  Or if it dipped back below 3500 would that count?

Comment: Yes, 4000 would be the next, and no, going below the threshold again should not count towards. Sorry, forgot to clarify that.

Comment: Also if it jumped straight to 4000 without the 3561, would this count as 2 or just one?  So `3001,3123,3342,3453,4025` would this be two or one?

Comment: Assuming those values are in A1:A5, you could enter `=FLOOR.MATH(A2,500)>FLOOR.MATH(A1,500)` into B2 and drag it down. Then you could count the values of `TRUE` in this range.

Comment: @Scott: The data will not grow fast enough to skip an entire threshold, so it won't matter.

Comment: Then we only care about the max and the min, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only care about how many time the number has increased by 500 from the start:

```
=INT((MAX($A$1:$A$5)-MIN($A$1:$A$5))/500)
```

---

As per your comments you can use this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INT((A2:A11-A1)/500)>INT((A1:A10-A1)/500)))
```

[image]

Column B is just to show where the numbers came from.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't think I was clear enough. The numbers can still drop down. Basically speaking, one can surpass the 3500 threshold multiple times, even when the all-time max is 4000 something. I just want to know how many times a threshold has been surpassed.

Comment: So if it dips down blow 3500 and then goes back above it gets counted again? `3001,3450,3565,3489,3569` would count 2?